# I can't log in to my wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to login this message appears

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in `E:\HostingSpaces\mahakram\acc.com.eg\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\redux-framework\ReduxCore\inc\themecheck\class.redux_themecheck.php`
>    on line 193

help me please

Comment: Did you miss any `::` in class.redux_themecheck.php on line 193 ?

Comment: Redux plugin has been update and its minimum requirement is PHP 5.3. May be you need to upgrade PHP in your hosting.

Comment: It seems that you are using the redux framework. I don't think there's a real chance they released it with a syntax error. Either you edited the files or you are running a different version of PHP than the one they require.

Comment: `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` error comes when you use `::` in PHP. This is supported for PHP > 5.3 OR (5.4?)

Comment: @TismonVarghese It is unexpected, so I doubt it's missing.

Comment: Check line 191 in this class. https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework/blob/3.5.5/ReduxCore/inc/themecheck/class.redux_themecheck.php

Comment: Upgrade your PHP version. Your current version died with the dinosaurs and is a huge security risk for your site

Answer (score 0):

try to install a previous version:

https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/redux-framework.3.5.4.3.zip